# Collection of Types and Instances with Contains/Any Functionality

Tags: c#

How can I create a collection of types and instances with Contains/ContainsKey/Any functionality? I've tried using dictionaries, valuetuple lists, and looked into other options, but am consistently stymied by `is a type, which is not valid in the given context` errors.

For example, here is my List + LINQ attempt with this error:

```
var activeReports = new List<(Type Type, IReport Instance)>();

if (activeReports.Any(x => x.Type == Reports.Daily))
{

};
```

and here is my dictionary attempt:

```
var activeReports = new Dictionary<Type, IReport>();

if (activeReports.ContainsKey(Reports.Daily))
{

};
```

In both attempts, the `is a type, which is not valid in the given context` error occurs on `Reports.Daily`.

Context: I'm trying to create a collection of active reports from a large group of possibilities.

Comment: `Type` is probably referring to `System.Type`, not to whatever you think it should be.

Comment: Side note: save yourself some pain and avoid reusing names of framework types/C# reserved words for names of your types/properties... `Type` is indeed common problem as it's nice to use it as "type of car", "type of message" as well as "the `Type` of object" and verb too to use as method name `foo.Type()`...but if you like such code just go all the way `var @if=true; var var = 42; if(@if) Console.Write(var);` :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: That's a matter of stylistic preference. I wouldn't equate naming variables after the classes they represent to variables after reserved keywords. Sometimes, in a general context, the only relevant identifier that makes sense _is_ the type name. That said, I certainly agree that if the context restricts the meaning of an object beyond its type, then it's useful to prefer more descriptive identifiers that clearly indicate that context—as the OP did with e.e.g `activeReports`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nomenclature starts to eat its own tail here, which is confusing. What you need to do is make sure you're sending the methods a [`Type` *object*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netframework-4.8), as opposed to the actual *type*. A `Type` object *describes* a type—and includes a ton of useful metadata about it.

You can get a `Type` object by using the built-in [`typeof()` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator) on the type (e.g., `typeof(Reports.Daily)`):

```cs
var activeReports = new Dictionary<Type, IReport>();

if (activeReports.ContainsKey(typeof(Reports.Daily))) { … }
```

Alternatively, if you already have an existing instance of a type, you can get its `Type` object dynamically at runtime by using the [`.GetType()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=netframework-4.8) on the existing object instance:

```cs
var dailyReport = new Reports.Daily();
var activeReports = new Dictionary<Type, IReport>();

if (activeReports.ContainsKey(dailyReport.GetType())) { … }
```

> *Note:* `GetType()` is defined on the base `Object` class and, thus, available to *all* objects in C#, regardless of their type.

Comment: I'm glad it resolved your issue! On hindsight, it would have been less confusing if Microsoft had named the `Type` class something like `TypeDescriptor` or `TypeMetadata` to differentiate the concepts. That's what I ended up doing on an open  source project I work on that ran into a really similar problem.

Comment: Can't upvote/accept again but just letting you know that I'm dealing with the same situation again, had lost a bit of mental clarity on it, and knew to come right back to your excellent answer.